# Python - Openpyexcel - Conditional formatting, How on earth do i apply the rule to a column, but highlight the row?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import CellIsRule

load the workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('output.xlsx')
get the active sheet
ws = wb.active
#make the value of L3 "P"
ws["L3"].value = "P"
>#make the value of L4 "F"
ws["L4"].value = "F"
#make the value of L5 "+"
ws["L5"].value = "+"
#make the value of L6 "-"
ws["L6"].value = "-"

blueFill = PatternFill(start_color='ADD8E6', end_color='ADD8E6', fill_type='solid')
rule1 = CellIsRule(operator='equal', formula=['$L$3'], stopIfTrue=True, fill=blueFill)

greenFill = PatternFill(start_color='90EE90', end_color='90EE90', fill_type='solid')
rule2 = CellIsRule(operator='equal', formula=['$L$4'], stopIfTrue=True, fill=greenFill)

redFill = PatternFill(start_color='FF0000', end_color='FF0000', fill_type='solid')
rule3 = CellIsRule(operator='equal', formula=['$L$5'], stopIfTrue=True, fill=redFill)

yellowFill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF00', end_color='FFFF00', fill_type='solid')
rule4 = CellIsRule(operator='equal', formula=['$L$6'], stopIfTrue=True, fill=yellowFill)

#add the rules to column K
ws.conditional_formatting.add('K2:K1000', rule1)
ws.conditional_formatting.add('K2:K1000', rule2)
ws.conditional_formatting.add('K2:K1000', rule3)
ws.conditional_formatting.add('K2:K1000', rule4)

 #save the changes
wb.save('output2.xlsx')
```

So ive made it this far and everything works the way i want it to, except, i cant seem to find a way to Highlight the row the cell is found on and not just the cell itself.

I just cant think of a way to write it.
Google has led me down some dead ends, so im hoping someone out there has accomplished this and can let me in on the trick!`

Comment: Your formulas are only being applied to the column. The range K2:K1000 means that column only. If you want to extend the highlight across rows the range must be all the columns in the row range. I.e. If there is data from A2 to K10000 and your wanting to highlight row 3 from Col A to Col K when it matches then A3:K3 must be in the range or only the individual cell K3 is highlighted. Therefore use the range A2:K1000 or whatever the row/column range is. Also I dont think your criteria will work, probably need to change to using formulas like '=$L$3=$K2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no luck with changing your code to extend the range, the following code sample will apply the CF as formulas across the col range A - K.
If you type any of your values in column K from K2 down (to K1000) the row from A to K is highlighted in your selected colour. See example image at the bottom.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import Rule


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('output.xlsx')
# get the active sheet
# ws = wb.active
ws = wb['Sheet1']
# make the value of L3 "P"
ws["L3"].value = "P"
# make the value of L4 "F"
ws["L4"].value = "F"
# make the value of L5 "+"
ws["L5"].value = "+"
# make the value of L6 "-"
ws["L6"].value = "-"

### Colour fill formats
blueFill = PatternFill(start_color='ADD8E6', end_color='ADD8E6', fill_type='solid')
greenFill = PatternFill(start_color='90EE90', end_color='90EE90', fill_type='solid')
redFill = PatternFill(start_color='FF0000', end_color='FF0000', fill_type='solid')
yellowFill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF00', end_color='FFFF00', fill_type='solid')

### Fill range with sheet row location
fill_dict = {3:blueFill, 4:greenFill, 5:redFill, 6:yellowFill}
### Conditional format range so a fill row will be across columns A to K
cf_range = '$A$2:$K$1000'
### Add Conditional Formats to the sheet
for row, fill in fill_dict.items():
    rule = Rule(type='expression', dxf=DifferentialStyle(fill=fill), stopIfTrue=True)
    rule.formula = [f'$L${row}=$K2']
    ws.conditional_formatting.add(cf_range, rule)

# save the changes
wb.save('output2.xlsx')
```

[image: Sample sheet]

Comment: thank you so very much, could you recommend some further reading for me so I can understand exactly whats happening here, I was having so much trouble with this!

Comment: This is pure Excel so I'm sure if you googled 'how to highlight row in condition formatting' you'd get the steps to do this in Excel. Then all your doing is applying that using Python and Openpyxl.